# Cannot compile in release mode in Nvidia Nsight Eclipse edition

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to compile my CUDA/C++ program in release mode, but i'm getting the following error:

```
    make all 
Building file: ../matching.cu
Invoking: NVCC Compiler
nvcc -O3 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -odir "" -M -o "matching.d" "../matching.cu"
nvcc --compile -O3 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=compute_30 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30  -x cu -o  "matching.o" "../matching.cu"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include/xmmintrin.h(1015): error: identifier "__builtin_ia32_vec_set_v4hi" is undefined

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include/xmmintrin.h(1116): error: identifier "__builtin_ia32_pshufw" is undefined

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include/emmintrin.h(1312): error: identifier "__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v8hi" is undefined

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include/emmintrin.h(1318): error: identifier "__builtin_ia32_vec_set_v8hi" is undefined

../matching.cu(104): warning: variable "device" is used before its value is set

../matching.cu(209): warning: variable "min" was declared but never referenced

4 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00000af7_00000000-6_matching.cpp1.ii".
make: *** [matching.o] Error 2

**** Build Finished ****
```

Do you guys know what's the reason of these messages? thank you.

I'm using NVIDIA Nsight eclipse edition with CUDA toolkit 5.0 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is not an officially supported platform for CUDA toolkit 5.0.   The officially supported platforms are listed in the release notes in the doc directory. Do you get errors like this (out of xmmintrin.h and emmintrin.h) regardless of which files you compile?  Perhaps you should show which files are included in `matching.cu`

Comment: These are the files I've included:

`#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>`

Comment: What happens if you compile a file with those include files and an empty main function? If you still get the same errors I would suggest switching to a supported platform.

Comment: Same issue with an empty main function. I think the platform is causing this indeed. Basically, CUDA toolkit 5.0 was supported for ubuntu 11.10 - 12.04. Is that possible to downgrade ubuntu? Btw, I cannot switch to a newer version of CUDA (5.5 or 6.0) because the 5.0 remains the newest compatible one with my nvidia driver 304 (which I cannot upgrade because of my hardware setup..)

Comment: I don't know how to downgrade Ubuntu. You could certainly start over with a fresh install of your desired Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved. This is due to the fact that CUDA toolkit 5.0 is not supported in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have changed my hardware (Newer graphics card) in order to be able to upgrade my NVIDIA driver which allowed me to install CUDA tookit 6.0 (Not officially supported in 14.04 so far, but has better compatibility)

Comment: Actually 14.04 is [not officially supported by CUDA 6](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#system-requirements) either.

Comment: Indeed, it's not officially supported but it won't last since the 14.04 is an LTS. What I meant is that it's more compatible with CUDA 6.0 than with CUDA 5.0.